# switching between multiple JPanels in CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

I'm working on a game and I am using a CardLayout to switch between different JPanels in the same JFrame.

**Problem:** I have a helpPanel that I can go to pushing a button in the main-menuPanel and pushing a button in the gamePanel.

**What I want:**
I want to be able to place a `JButton` in my `helpPanel` that (when pressed) goes back to the main-menuPanel or the gamePanel (depending if you came from the main-menuPanel or from the gamePanel).

**What I've tried:** I've tried using the `actionlistener` in combination with `.previous(container parent)` but that only takes me back to the `JPanel` that was added to the `CardLayout` in the position previous to the helpPanel. I've also tried nesting the `actionListeners` to try and get different situations but that didn't work.

**What I searched:** I've searched for solutions in other Questiones but it's always about switching between 2 different `JPanels` in stead of 3.

Can anyone help me please? I find it to be a very difficult situation.

Comment: Why just don't you store in someplace a String variable call `previous` ?

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). It shows you how to switch between cards by specifying a String that identifies the card to display.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a game menu recently(which you'll see bits and pieces of here), and one way to do it is to have a common ActionListener for all the panel's buttons within. then set their action commands to have specific Strings.
in this example, overallgame is the master CardLayout panel. GAME, CREDITS, and MAIN-MENU are String constants used to title panels inside the overallgame panel

```html
ActionListener listener=new ActionListener()
   {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("start")){
     //dummyframe.add(newgame);
     //mainmenupanel=null;
     CardLayout layout=(CardLayout)(overallgame.getLayout());//retrieves the overall layout
     layout.show(overallgame, GAME);//uses it to switch to main game panel
     newgame.requestFocus(true);//need to redirect focus to the game rather than original main menu
     dummyframe.repaint();
     }
    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("show credits")){
     CardLayout layout=(CardLayout)(overallgame.getLayout());
     layout.show(overallgame, CREDITS);
     }

    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("switch to main")){
     CardLayout layout=(CardLayout)(overallgame.getLayout());
     layout.show(overallgame, MAIN_MENU);
     }
    
    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("show chapter panel")){
     CardLayout layout=(CardLayout)(overallgame.getLayout());
     layout.show(overallgame, CHAPTERSTART);
     }
    else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hey");
     }
    }
   };​
```

as you can see, the above ActionCommands used are specific Strings. you can set a JButton to have an ActionCommand like "start" with a line like this(with using my pre-defined listener, that will switch to panel with my in-progress game)
, causing the NewGame JButton to have an ActionEvent with the ActionCommand, "start" whenever clicked.

```html
NewGame.setActionCommand("start");​
```

to make a panel have a title that can be used by the CardLayout, you have to define the name when adding the panel to the CardLayout. this line adds a JPanel called mainmenupanel to my overallgame JPanel, and then allows the overallgame panel to refer to it with the String constant MAIN_MENU.

```html
overallgame.add(mainmenupanel, MAIN_MENU);​
```

as you can see, conditionally analyzing your pre-set ActionCommands on an overridden ActionListener to then use the CardLayout to show a particular JPanel is a good way to do what you want.
Hope this helps!(I just did this recently too, so I was at a loss for a while, too).
feel free to comment to ask questions if I wasn't completely clear